# clientside nodejs readline not triggering 'close' event except on CTRL-C from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, readline

I am trying to make a simple server/client TCP connection with javascript using nodejs.

I have `client.js` code (which I can't modify) which has this line:

```
var s = net.connect({port: this._port}),
        rl = readline.createInterface({input: s});
s.write('quit\r\n');
rl.on('close', () => done(null, output));
```

The problem is, I cannot get that event to trigger. On the server side, I have

```
    socket.once("close", function () {
        console.log("Connection from %s closed", remoteAddress);
        // socket.destroy();
    });

    socket.once("end", function() {
        console.log("Ending connection");
        // socket.destroy();
    })
```

The server side receives an end event, and prints it out, followed by the close. However, I can't seem to get that client to get that end event naturally. Something weird that does work though, is if I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the server and stop it midway. That causes the client to get the 'end' and move on with the code. As of now, it just timeouts. Now I am wondering if it's possible to automatically send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or if there is any other way to get this 'end' to trigger.

Methods I have tried: 
`socket.destroy()`, sending EOT character.

Again, I cannot modify this `client.js`.